# how to add img tag in the a js file

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

how can i add img tags in this js code so that in the table instead of getting a link and img appears

so where there is pic in the table i want an image not a link to appear there.

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("imageurl");
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
  var pic = snap.child("url").val();
  var name = snap.child("name").val();
  var nationality = snap.child("nationality").val();
  var birthday = snap.child("dob").val();
  var height = snap.child("height").val();
  var position = snap.child("category").val();
  var foot= snap.child("foot").val();
  var weight = snap.child("weight").val();
  var transfer = snap.child("transferLink").val();
  var youtube = snap.child("youtubeLink").val();

  $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + pic + "</td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + nationality + "</td><td>" + birthday +  "</td><td>" + height +
   "</td><td>" + position +  "</td><td>" + foot +  "</td><td>" + weight +  "</td><td>" + transfer +
    "</td><td>" + youtube + "</td><td><button>Remove</button></td></tr>");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("imageurl");
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
  var pic = snap.child("url").val();
  var name = snap.child("name").val();
  var nationality = snap.child("nationality").val();
  var birthday = snap.child("dob").val();
  var height = snap.child("height").val();
  var position = snap.child("category").val();
  var foot= snap.child("foot").val();
  var weight = snap.child("weight").val();
  var transfer = snap.child("transferLink").val();
  var youtube = snap.child("youtubeLink").val();

  $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + "<img src='" + pic + "' >" + "</td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + nationality + "</td><td>" + birthday +  "</td><td>" + height +
   "</td><td>" + position +  "</td><td>" + foot +  "</td><td>" + weight +  "</td><td>" + transfer +
    "</td><td>" + youtube + "</td><td><button>Remove</button></td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: thank you so much @Andrii ...and how would i add dimensions to the image because
 "<img height="42" width="42" src=" + pic + ">"
hasn't worked))

Comment: You can add custom class or id to this `img` tag. And then style it.

Comment: Also you can vote this answer as a right answer. So it would be helpful for somebody in the future.